# The curse to the dvarapalakas of Vishnu by the sons of Brahma

Tags: vishnu, krishna, vaishnavism, avatars, bhagavata-purana

Vishnu, the infinite manifestation knows everything that will happen in the future? Did he already know the Brahma Putra would curse Jaya and Vijaya? Was it all Vishnu's leela to get into the Material World? Could someone throw light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, this was all the plan of Vishnu.

First, let's see what the Srimad Bhagavatam Purana says about Vishnu's avatars:

> 6. At first, that very God manifested Himself as the sages who are older than seems (lit. youthful-old) and upon becoming a Brāhmaṇa, practised unbroken celibacy which is difficult to practise. (Srimad Bhagavatam, Book I, Chapter 3)

Here, Sūta references to Śaunnaka that the Four Kumaras are divine incarnations of Vishnu.

This is further explained later in the Purana when Brahma explains to Narada of Vishnu's incarnations:

> 5. **In the beginning (of the creation) when I performed penance with a desire to create various worlds and beings, He incarnated as the four sages whose names begin with Sana (Sanatkumāra, Sanaka, Sanandana, Sanātana), by my offering of my penance.** He accurately explained the real nature of ātman or Brahma which was lost in the deluge of the previous Kalpa. Sages instantaneously realized the soul (Ātman) as soon as it (his explanation of the nature of the soul) was heard by them. (Srimad Bhagavatam, Book II, Chapter 7)

In the Garuda Purana, Sūta tells Śaunnaka and other Rishis in the Namisha Forest about Vishnu's incarnations. He starts off with the Kumaras.

> SUTA said:—I will describe the Garuda Purana, the essence of all accounts relating to Vishnu. Formerly Garuda described it to Kashyapa and I myself had heard it from Vyasa. The Lord Narayana alone is the lord of all the lords of the deities, the great soul and the great Brahma; from him proceeds birth. For the protection of the universe Vasudeva, without birth and death, assumes various incarnations by his body, namely that of Kaumara and others. Having undertaken the incarnation of Kaumara and lived in the celestial region the first deity Hari, O Brahman, practised the most difficult vow of celebacy without any break. (Garuda Purana, Book I, Chapter I)

Vishnu was cursed by Rishi Bhrigu to continuously be reborn with humans for seven times. This was because Kavyamata, the mother of Asuraguru Shukracharya, stood in front of the demons to protect them from Indra, Vishnu angry Indra was in trouble killed her.

> 139-140. Thereafter, bearing in mind, that Indra was in trouble, lord the destroyer of the enemies of Suras, hastened Viṣṇu in his action. He wanted to be quicker than the mother of Kāvya who was also in a hurry. **Viṣṇu was aware that what he was desirous of doing was a cruel deed. Becoming furious he pierced her head with his weapon and cut it into three parts.** (Brahmanda Purana, Book III, Chapter 72)

He later beared the consequences:

> 141. On observing that horrible slaughter, of a woman his wife, Bhṛgu the powerful one became angry. Then, due to the murder of his wife, Viṣṇu was cursed by Bhṛgu.
> 142. “Since a woman who should not be killed has been killed by you, though you are conversant with what is righteousness, you will have to take birth among human beings for seven times”.
> 143. Thereafter on account of that curse the lord is born again and again among human beings here (in this world), for the welfare of all the worlds, whenever there is a destruction of piety and virtue. (Brahmanda Purana, Book III, Chapter 72)

However, in the Bhagavad Gita, Krishna says to Arjuna that He Himself is Bhrigu.

> **I am Bhrigu amongst the great seers** and the transcendental Om amongst sounds. Amongst chants know Me to be the repetition of the Holy Name; amongst immovable things I am the Himalayas. (Bhagavad Gita, 10.25)

So, Vishnu cursed Himself so He could incarnate on Earth and establish righteousness for us, the insignificant humans!

Of course, now Vishnu needed enemies in his great Avatars, so he accepted the curse brought by the Kumaras, who themselves are Vishnu.

> 2-3. Oh sages, as these two servants of mine, Jaya and Vijaya, disregarding me, have gravely insulted you and slighted gods, I have approved of the punishment meted out to them by you who perform penance for me.
>
> 4. I, therefore, apologize to you today, for the Brāhmaṇas are my highest deity. I regard that the offence given to you by my servants is as good as done by me. (Bhagavad Gita, Book III, Chapter 16)

> **The Lord said:**
> 26. “Oh Brāhmaṇas, please note that this curse of yours was ordained by me. These two will immediately take birth as non-heavenly beings (Daityas). Having developed their yoga by concentration intensified by wrath, both these will soon return to me.”
>
> **Brahmā said:**
> 27-28. “Then the sages, having seen Viṣṇu, the receptacle of delight to the eyes, and his abode, the self-illuminating Vaikuṇṭha, circumambulated the Lord, bowed down to him. Taking leave of him, they returned, full of joy, praising the glory of Viṣṇu.
>
> 29. Lord Viṣṇu said to his servants, “You go (now). Do not be afraid. May you be happy. Though I am competent to do so, I do not wish to counteract the power of Brāhmaṇas, as it is my will.

I hope this was helpful!